# Discord.py Как получить список участников онлайн на сервере в discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Я хочу написать бота, который выводил бы сообщение в консоль, когда кто-то заходит в сеть на моем дискорд сервере.
Но я не могу получить участников онлайн.
member.status, возвращает "offline" для тех кто в сети и не в сети. В доках discord py, я не нашел функцию, которая возвращала бы только онлайн юзеров

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
Token = 'My bot token'
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)              
@client.event
async def on_ready():                                       
        for server in client.guilds:
            print(server)
        for member in server.members:                               
            print(member, "-", member.status)                                                                                                        
client.run(Token)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот список юзеров online, idle, offline, dnd

```py
mbrs = ctx.guild.members
online = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.status == discord.Status.online, mbrs)))
idle = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.status == discord.Status.idle, mbrs)))
offline = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.status == discord.Status.offline, mbrs)))
dnd = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.status == discord.Status.dnd, mbrs)))
```